# What is In[] in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am learning python by myself and I searched for in operator in net but I could not understand what it does exactly mean in here

```
In[11]:3+2
Out[11]:5
In[12]:print(3+2)
5
```

Please excuse my ignorance am just new to python.

Comment: It's not Python code at all; they are just "cell identifiers" in `jupyter`/iPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They identifies cells in an iPython/Jupyter notebook. Cells enclosing input prompts use `In[x]`, where `x` is just a serial number you can use to refer to previous inputs. `Out[x]` is the cell containing the output of the corresponding `In` cell.

Your example shows an input of `3 + 2`, following by its value. `print(3+2)` is likewise an input, but the `5` is simply text written to standard output. As the input expression had the value `None` (the return value of the `print` function), no output cell was created.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are typing this out in a Jupyter Notebook or a Python Editor. In and Out here means Input and Output.